# Define single messageBox with various strings in a list, using foreach loop, possible?

Tags: c#, foreach, messagebox

I have various strings in a var set

```
var linhas = new[] { line8, line9, line10}
```

I wanna display them all in a single messagebox, but! I don't wanna display those who are empty, so i'm using the following

```
foreach (var l in linhas)
    if (l != null)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(l);
    }
```

But it only shows one message at a time, as predicted. Is it possible somehow to remove the null lines from a list, and display only those other than null in a single MessageBox?

```
MessageBox.Show(linenotnull8 + "\n" + linenotnull10);
```

Comment: Add the `!null` items to a list, then show those?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the following, you can filter out `null` strings, then use `String.Join` to create a single string from the remaining strings in `linhas`, separating each string with a carriage return.

```
MessageBox.Show(String.Join(Environment.NewLine, linhas.Where(x => x != null)));
```

Side note... I used [`Environment.NewLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.newline(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of `'\n'` because it will use the correct line feed character depending on the environment you're running in (Windows vs Unix).

> A string containing "\r\n" for non-Unix platforms, or a string containing "\n" for Unix platforms.

Comment: Hmm not clear, if I create a `String.Join` how will the rest of the sentence know where to separate the new line? Also in the code you only filter out at the end???

Comment: No i didn't, i was barely understanding how it was working, but that comment cleared it all, thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

To check for Null or Empty values in the array use `string.IsNullOrEmpty`:

Here is solution using linq:

```
linhas = linhas.Where(x => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(x)).ToArray();
string s = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, linhas);
MessageBox.Show(s);
```

Answer (score 1):

another option, with your existing set, you can use `String Builder`

I also add String checking `null` or `empty`

```
sb StringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for(int i = 0; i < linhas.Length ; i++)
if (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(linhas[i]))
  sb.AppendFormat("{0}{1}" , linhas[i] , Environment.NewLine);

MessageBox.Show(sb.toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

It would b better to use StringBuilder:

```
StringBuilder sb=new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var l in linhas)
    if (l != null)
    {
        sb.AppendLine(l);
    }
MessageBox.Show(sb.ToString());
```

If you don't want to show empty Strings as well you must change your if condition:

```
if(!String.IsNullOrEmpty(l) && l!="")
```